# unexpected end of file in etc/profile in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

**Below is etc profile How to revert the profile file the error i am getting is unexpected end of file in etc/profile  in ubuntu

Thanks in advance.
**

```
# /etc/profile: system-wide .profile file for the Bourne shell (sh(1))
# and Bourne compatible shells (bash(1), ksh(1), ash(1), ...).

if [ "$PS1" ]; then
  if [ "$BASH" ] && [ "$BASH" != "/bin/sh" ]; then
    # The file bash.bashrc already sets the default PS1.
    # PS1='\h:\w\$ '
    if [ -f /etc/bash.bashrc ]; then
      . /etc/bash.bashrc
    fi
  else
    if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
      PS1='# '
    else
      PS1='$ '
    fi
  fi


# The default umask is now handled by pam_umask.
# See pam_umask(8) and /etc/login.defs.

if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
  for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r $i ]; then
      . $i
    fi
  done
  unset i
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `fi` for the main `if` in first block.

```
if [ "$PS1" ]; then                                                                                                                                                        
    if [ "$BASH" ] && [ "$BASH" != "/bin/sh" ]; then
        # The file bash.bashrc already sets the default PS1.
        # PS1='\h:\w\$ '
        if [ -f /etc/bash.bashrc ]; then
            . /etc/bash.bashrc
        fi
    else
        if [ `id -u` -eq 0 ]; then
            PS1='# '
        else
            PS1='$ '
        fi
    fi
fi
```

And when you are comparing(`` [ `id -u` -eq 0 ] ``), either use variables in double quotes on both sides of the comparison or do not use quotes at all. If you are using quote on one side and not on other side, you will be comparing a number to a string.